# Replacement for XP

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, windows-xp

What is the best set-up to replace Windows XP on a .Samsung netbook? This would have to be done without using an optical drive (hence must be done using a thumb drive). Experience of computing is very limited, and even more so with Linux, so cannot use complex coding methods.

Answer (score 3):

On a netbook, I'd recommend one of the less graphically taxing Ubuntu versions, [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).

Then, follow the official instructions on [how to create a bootable USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) using the ISO you downloaded.

Instruct your netbook to boot from the USB drive. With Samsung machines, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> directly after turning on the machine usually brings up a prompt to select the boot device.

Then, use the guided installation to install your chosen flavor of Ubuntu to your hard disk.

Comment: Just beat me to it :-)

Comment: We are running 12.04 LTS with Unity on an NC10 (with 2GB RAM) and Voria tools here, no issues.